# PostgreSQL - Duplicate table in parts, empty other fields, rename table

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql

I'm very new to PostgreSQL or SQL in general, so I don't know whether my question might be simple and stupid – sorry in advance.

My situation is the following:

- I've got a table with 57 columns and 219 entries
- I need the table every year
- data of some columns should be transferred to the duplicated table (e.g. the first four columns)
- the other columns should be emptied
- the table got a trigger which should be also tranferred to the new table
- the name of the table is like "xxx_2017" and the name of the new table should be "xxx_2018"

*Note: the whole procedure will be binded to a button on a php-website in the end*

I think the first steps should be pure SQL with some special adjusted SELECT (`CREATE TABLE xx AS SELECT … FROM yy`), but the renaming seems to be more complicated because I need to save the last four digits of the name of my 'old' table into a variable as an `INT` or similar and need to count it up before I can give the variable to the name of my 'new' table.

I know that I'm asking a question without having much groundwork and I don't expect a complete and working solution – of course you're free to post one anyway, if you want. But what I need is some advice an help to get this working.

Thanks!

---

**EDIT 1**
What I know is that I could ducplicate the table with all data (`SELECT *`) and delete data afterwards like `UPDATE table_name SET column1 = NULL, column2 = NULL, column3 = NULL`. But I would need to update 53 columns because I only need the data of 4 columns.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution to the `create table xxx_2018 as select * from xxx_2017;' is to use`create table ... like ...` construct (it creates table only, also gives option for copying constraints etc; does not copies data):

```
create table xxx_2018 like xxx_2017 including all;
insert into xxx_2018(<<4 columns you would like to fill>>) select <<4 columns you would like to fill>> from xxx_2017;
create trigger xxx_2018_trigger ... on xxx_2018 execute procedure trigger_procedure();
```

Reference:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html ("LIKE" paragraph)